# Make excel file only readable from pc screen

Tags: excel, readonly, copy-protection

Is there a way to make an EXCEL file ONLY open and readable from screen? No copy for the whole file neither its contents, prevent it to be attached in mail, deleted or modified.

It's not the case of password protecting it as it will be open to someone on his computer but this person has to get some info from it without editing it, and without being able to copy it or mail it to himself.

Thanks.

Comment: No.  If it's electronic, there's always a way to work around what you've done to prevent it.  Is hindrance enough or do you really mean ONLY.  Best I could think of would be to display it as a image so the text can't be selected.

Comment: I mean that the agent have to work on it, but not steal contact information from it

Comment: use excel to save it as a PDF... Can be searched but not modified/copied.

Comment: and then the PDF itself will be copied as a whole

Comment: This is true.... which is why I think No is likely the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect the workbook with a password.  It is the VERY top most item under the File section in any Excel file.

You won't be able to stop it from being copied around.  But you can prevent people from editing it.

Comment: Sorry for not well explaining the case, please review the edits.

Comment: Yeah, what you're asking for is impossible.  I mean, even if you could lock the file down completely, there is nothing stopping someone from screengrabbing it, or even taking a picture with their cell phone.

Comment: Actually you can disable print screen and other export functions. The cell phone picture is impossible to disable as it's not controlled by the computer's software.

Answer (score 0):

I work for a copy protection company. I will try my best not being biased by my work.

What you are asking for, as I understand it, is "copy protection". You want your content to be safe from sharing.

It's possible to do as you ask for, but this require you hook into the excel program and block all export functions. You can also force your file to only be viewed in an excel viewer with no export functions. This will require you encrypt your xls file, which makes it impossible to launch without a guard program that will decrypt the file and control the export API's. You can read more about copy protection in this article: [All About Copy Protection](http://linkdata.com/theory.htm)

Will it be impossible for hackers to break your protection? All code can be broken by good hackers, but it will make it un-shareable for your normal users, which in most cases is enough.